# IIS worker process: Cache % Process Memory Used is more than 100 %, how is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, perfmon

PerfMon counter  : Cache % Process Memory Used is more than 100 % . How is this possible??

Note : only one worker process was running, hosting one website.

[image: Howz this Possible]

Answer (score 1):

There are upper and lower limits imposed on IIS worker processes.  It could have surpassed on one of these limits briefly before recycling the Application pool to get memory consumption back down to a more reasonable level.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a rounding error, or dirty data gathering, or the process may be in virtual memory.  Is the box thrashing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Mashin.config that indicates the total usage of cache it is by default in 60% of the total memory if its changed somehow you might reach that level. please also check your web.config file for the setting of cache

Answer (score 0):

**[Cache % Process Memory Used] 

    = [Memory consumed by worker process] * 100 / [Memory Limit imposed on Cache]**

There is no reason why "Memory consumed by worker process" can't exceed "Memory Limit imposed on Cache". When "Memory consumed by worker process" > "Memory Limit imposed on Cache", value of this counter will be greater than 100.

Reference : Search for "Cache Memory Percentages" Section in [Msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/07/20/monitor-your-asp-net-cache-api-behaviour.aspx)